# How to dynamically add filter queries in angular?

Tags: angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-click, ng-filter

I'm wondering if I can dynamically change filter queries in angular. If not, what are the other options?

```
<a ng-repeat="topic in data.topics">
<button ng-click="topicFilter= {topic: '{{topic.label}}'">{{topic.label}}</button>
</a>
```

My goal is to provide a list of buttons that dynamically sets up filters based on {{topic.label}}.

My first approach was below, but this will be too many lines of codes if my topic increases:

```
<a ng-repeat="topic in data.topics">
<button ng-click="topicFilter= {topic: 'D3'">{{topic.label}}</button>
<button ng-click="topicFilter= {topic: 'Angular'">{{topic.label}}</button>
<button ng-click="topicFilter= {topic: 'React'">{{topic.label}}</button>
<button ng-click="topicFilter= {topic: 'Redis'">{{topic.label}}</button>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first approach was solid, though I would use the repeater on the buttons themselves. Also I suggest using a function to make the action happen, that way in the future it will be easy to change in one place.

```
<button ng-repeat="topic in data.topics"
        ng-click="setFilter('topic', topic.label);">{{topic.label}}</button>
```

---

```
$scope.setFilter = function(type, value) {
    $scope[type+'Filter'] = {};
    $scope[type+'Filter'][type] = value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a function. Something like this:

```
<a ng-repeat="topic in data.topics">
  <button ng-click="topicFilter = tf(topic)">{{topic.label}}</button>
</a>
```

And, in controller:

```
$scope.tf = function(topic) {
  return { topic: topic.label };
};
```